# How to speed up the following python3 code?

Tags: python-3.x

So i'm trying to parse a huge file and the code below is taking too long to parse. The File is 2gb in size. I'm hoping some can help me speed it up.

```
import os, shlex

def extractLinkField(inDir, outDir):
    fileList = os.listdir(inDir)
    links = set()

    for File in fileList:
        print(File)
        with open(os.path.join(inDir, File), encoding="utf8") as inFile:
            for line in inFile:
                try:
                    links.add(shlex.split(line)[2])
                except Exception:
                    continue

        outFile = open(os.path.join(outDir, 'extractedLinks.txt'), 'a+', encoding="utf8")
        for link in list(links):
            outFile.write(link + '\n')
        outFile.close()

Path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logs')
extractLinkField(Path, os.getcwd())
```

File format is as follows:

```
90 "m  z pd gk y xr   vo" "n l v   ogtc  dj wzb" "d  zi  pfgyo b tmhek" "df qu  venr ls hzw j"
82 "p  wgd lv f kt eb uq" " ij   cw  v a r y qp" "  pf qdlcgm jz  os y" "f xm   n  cr  ublzig"
89 "c  pgib  a   ost whk" "ria m h  fvcb  es  z" "qzoy g xbr      makc" "ms    lqc v  ektb w "
66 "zxm pe hb  vi   dj  " "rg  ebfwp y  zv oakm" "b nut ko je  m  crsh" " imsxtzfw  g ka j l "
2 "uyhnpt  l dj qak    " "o hned j  pqub t a  " "v  hlyc   afwi sgr p" "h wtvi g o  nc sujqx"
17 "apo ufliz  qctbd xh " "k  lxgbrcwzf mnhtq p" "z    gk   m   rsbu l" "  ds  m au w cior   "
9 "  h t  ac  jpn ok mz" "aty rs w box vk zefp" "nm fbc x egt  zruap " "xg  oi j z wyf v dqp"
82 "xs q  ve     k oi c " " z lfa  dwiprxb ku g" "kua p  f  b oqz jrt " "   t wlvy d po qrx e"
51 "cx   iq wuvhb gkmo y" " u p yx    bv mjz  r" "oatc wuxd yfgjs  ri " "vbg  w     h ife myl"
91 "cdqkp rn  u ow   h f" "ko rt y c eis d q jl" "  lv fe r zpju yw   " "  wz  vtxa  jn lg  s"
83 "bts   dl kjycre ozv " " k  i q m r ypsu lh " "pr exw sznqa  yvu i " "  uq   tzk nomrx  e "
```

Please note that the strings in the file wrapped by the quotes should not be split and must be parsed out as whole (that is still  wrapped in the quotes)

[image: Sample output and directory structure:]

Comment: If you are going to down vote my question, please explain why you are doing it. Thanks.

Comment: can you please include say 10 lines of the file you are trying to parse so that I can try to write you a quick Pandas parser?

Comment: Yep, I'll do it right now @Matt

Comment: I've added it to the post @Matt thanks for the help.

Comment: Any other demands except to ignore quoted strings when splitting?

Comment: I know there are duplicates in the data so duplicates must be removed. That is all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is, obviously, `shlex.split()`. It's quite an expensive operation (creates a whole new object with a lot of boilerplate for each split), so if your data follows the format presented you can try parsing your data manually.

So, here's a method that performs the same way on your sample data as `shlex.split()`:

```
def manual_split(data):
    data = data.strip()  # clear artifacts
    tokens = []
    head = 0
    open_quote = False
    while True:
        if open_quote:
            quote = data.find('"', head)
            if quote == -1:  # this should not happen, no matching quotes
                break
            tokens.append(data[head:quote])
            head = quote + 1
            open_quote = False
        else:
            space = data.find(' ', head)
            quote = data.find('"', head)
            if space == -1 and quote == -1:  # nothing more to split
                break
            if space < quote:
                if not tokens or space - head > 1:
                    tokens.append(data[head:space])
                head = space + 1
                open_quote = False
            else:
                open_quote = True
                head = quote + 1
    if head < len(data):  # add leftovers, if any, as the last token
        tokens.append(data[head:])
    return tokens
```

Compared to `shlex.split()`, running over the same sample data (including the loop) here are some times for you:

```
shlex.split:  10,000 loops: 11.51 s, per loop: 1.151 ms
manual_split: 10,000 loops: 0.951 s, per loop: 95.11 µs
```

So, more than 12 times faster. But we can do better... The problem with this approach is that it has plenty of slow `str.find()` calls (although going character by character would be even slower) and string shuffling on the Python side so the fast C side doesn't get the chance to do its magic. If you were to implement this in C (with a few optimizations) and load it as a module it would be blazingly fast, but alas...

So, I thought `regex` might do it faster given that it executes mostly on the C side of things, and even if you give it more complex rules it should be able to outperform pure Python string searching & manipulation over large enough data. So, the next candidate:

```
import re

FIELDS_PATTERN = re.compile(r"(?:\"(.*?)\"|(\S+))")

def regex_split(data):
    return [x[0] or x[1] for x in FIELDS_PATTERN.findall(data)]
```

And now we have the final benchmark:

```
shlex.split:  10,000 loops: 11.51 s, per loop: 1.151 ms
manual_split: 10,000 loops: 0.951 s, per loop: 95.11 µs
regex_split:  10,000 loops: 0.482 s, per loop: 48.16 µs
```

Yes, the regex one is almost 24x faster than `shlex.split()`! And they all produce the same split result for your test data.

**BUT** before you jump in and kick out `shlex`, you need to thoroughly test both of these to make sure they fit your data - for example, they don't recognize escaped quotes or special POSIX unraveling of quoted strings so if you have such cases in your data you'll have to take that into account.

Also, unrelated, if you want to add a tiny bit of speed up, write to your output immediately instead of storing in a set just to loop through it at a later time:

```
with open(os.path.join(out_dir, 'extractedLinks.txt'), 'a+', encoding="utf8") as out_file:
    links = set()  # temp store to ensure uniqueness...
    for current_file in file_list:
        with open(os.path.join(in_dir, current_file), encoding="utf8") as in_file:
            for line in in_file:
                try:
                    link = shlex.split(line)[2]  # or whatever other function
                    if link not in links:
                        links.add(link)
                        out_file.write(link + "\n")
                except Exception:
                    continue
```

Under the assumption that you'll gather millions of lines in that huge input file of yours, this could shave off a second or two...

Comment: nice answer, I was going to drop in a pandas version but it seems your benchmarks negate the need

Comment: wow :o mind blown. Thank you for so much detail. I learned a lot from your answer.